# proving that a set is countably infinite

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Alright, I have this homework problem "Show that the following sets are countably infinite, by defining a bijection between
N (or Z+) and that set. You do not need to prove that your function is bijective."

The set in question is {1,2,3} x Z. I really do not even know where to start with this problem, I understand what bijective is and since we don't need to prove it we don't need to show that the functions are one-to-one and onto.

How do I go about defining a bijection?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $f(3n+i)=\{i\}\times\{n\}$ for $n\neq0$ and $i=1$, $2$, $3$. Can you correct this construction to obtain the desired bijection?